# Prevent Google App script from executing in parallel

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Google App script that is being executed by clicking on an floating image on a sheet.

How can I prevent people from running the script AGAIN before it is finished with the first execution?

It seems that you can execute the script multiple times by clicking the image and that the subsequent executions conflict with the previous ones and cause erroneous results.

I was going to temporarily disassociate the script with the floating image while it is running an then restore it before exiting the script but I can't seem to find a way to manipulate the floating image's properties.

Comment: If you use buttons on a dialog or a sidebar you can disable the button in javascript and then enable it again with a callback function after the script is completed. Check out [success handlers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication).  I don't think that you can do this with images used as buttons on the spreadsheet itself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For client side handling, you can assign a value to a variable to identify the status of function.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <img src="http://cdn.soulsplay.com/assets//listing/css/comments/submit-button-2.png" onclick="invokeSubmit();">
  </body>
  <script>

    var image_clicked = 0;

    function invokeSubmit(){
      image_clicked ++;
      if(image_clicked == 1){
        alert("Processing");
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(){
          image_clicked = 0;
          alert("done");
        }).sleep_func();
      }
    }
  </script>
</html>
```

**code.gs**

```
function doGet() {
  var output = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index').evaluate();
  output.setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
  output.setTitle('App Script');
  return output;
}

function sleep_func(){
  Utilities.sleep(15000);
  return;
}
```

You can also prevent the script from concurrent access by using [Lock Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock/).

```
function test_func(){
  var lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
  lock.waitLock(15000);

  //Some operations

  lock.releaseLock();
}
```

Comment: Perfect!!! That last suggestion, LockService, is exactly what I needed.  Thanks so much

Comment: Excellent idea. I'd like to point out an important detail in the locking pattern the solution is missing. When locking you want to ensure you release the lock upon function exit no matter what. 

I suggest developing a habit of using `try {} finally {}` and always releasing locks in a `finally` clause, encasing potentially failing operations in a `try`.

`function test_func(){
  var lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
  lock.waitLock(15000);
  try {
    /* Some operations, any can raise an exception */
  } finally {
    lock.releaseLock();
  }
}`

Comment: Agreed. @Victor